# Merge multiple tiff files into one tiff file maintaining shape

Tags: python, numpy, tiff

With tifftools I merged 10 tif files into one single tif file, but when I open it with skimage.io.imread() ad I check the shape with the .shape() function, it gives me [512, 512] instead of [10, 512, 512].
If I save the tif images in a single with ImageJ instead, I get the correct shape.

Here the code I used:

```
img_lst = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    img_lst.append('source_folder/image'+i+'.tif')

img0 = tifftools.read_tiff(img_lst[0])
for i in range(1, 10):
    img1 = tifftools.read_tiff(img_lst[i])
    img0['ifds'].extend(img1['ifds'])
        
tifftools.write_tiff(img0, 'folder_dest/image.tif')
```

Is there anything else I can use to keep the shape correct?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import os
import sys

import tifftools
from skimage.io import imread


def main(*argv):
    img_in_names = glob.glob("img*.tif")
    if not img_in_names:
        print("No image!!!")
        return -1
    print("File names: {:}".format(img_in_names))
    t = tifftools.read_tiff(img_in_names[0])
    for img_in_name in img_in_names[1:]:
        t["ifds"].extend(tifftools.read_tiff(img_in_name)["ifds"])

    img_out_name = "combine.tif"
    if os.path.isfile(img_out_name):
        os.unlink(img_out_name)
    tifftools.write_tiff(t, img_out_name)

    imgo = imread(img_out_name)
    imgs = [imread(e) for e in img_in_names]

    print("Output file details: {:}, {:}".format(imgo.shape, imgo.dtype))
    print("Input files details: {:}".format([(img.shape, img.dtype) for img in imgs]))

    if len(img_in_names) in (3, 4):  # @TODO:
        imgo = imgo.transpose((2, 0, 1))

    print("Matching arrays: {:}".format([(imgo[i] == img).all() for i, img in enumerate(imgs)]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073950989]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> File names: ['img_01.tif', 'img_02.tif', 'img_03.tif', 'img_04.tif', 'img_05.tif']
> Output file details: (5, 480, 640), uint8
> Input files details: [((480, 640), dtype('uint8')), ((480, 640), dtype('uint8')), ((480, 640), dtype('uint8')), ((480, 640), dtype('uint8')), ((480, 640), dtype('uint8'))]
> Matching arrays: [True, True, True, True, True]
>
> Done.
> ```

One interesting thing that came up (and needs to be payed attention to) is when having 3 or 4 input files.
When reading the out file *skimage.io.imread* returns a *3D* array, but its format is ***HWC*** (with ***C*** = ***RGB*** (***RGBA***)) instead one that is a list of *HW* arrays, and thus needs transposition (the ***@TODO*** line).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your code but it still don't work. Here my result:
`Output file details: (512, 512), uint8`
`Input files details: [((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8')), ((512, 512), dtype('uint8'))]`
`Matching arrays: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]`

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Perhaps you could share the images so I can give it a try...